# How to get only 1.0 and 0.5 values with LINQ to SQL?

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a list of parameters going from -20,00 to 20,00 by step 0,25.
Sometimes I need the whole list but in some cases I only need the parameters by step 0.50
ex : in the values 1.00 ; 1.25; 1.50 ; 1.75 ; 2.00 ; 2.25; 2.50 ; 2.75 ; 3.00 i only need  1.00 ; 1.50 ; 2.00 ; 2.50 ; 3.00

I've tried this

```
 return From le In dbiLens.Lens
             Join dia In dbiLens.LensDiameters On dia.DiameterID Equals le.DiameterID
             Join krom In dbiLens.LensKrommings On krom.KrommingID Equals le.KrommingID
             Join sterk In dbiLens.LensSterktes On sterk.SterkteID Equals le.SterkteID       
    Where Right(CStr(le.Sterkte), 2) <> "25" Or Right(CStr(le.Sterkte), 2) <> "75"
        Where (le.TypeID = pLensTypeID AndAlso le.GebruiksduurID = pLensPeriodeID _
        AndAlso dia.Diameter = pLensDiaMin _
        AndAlso krom.Kromming = pLensKromMin _
        AndAlso sterk.Sterkte >= pLensSterkteMin AndAlso sterk.Sterkte <= LensSterkteMax)
                                Select le
```

And tried this

```
Return From le In dbiLens.Lens
         Join dia In dbiLens.LensDiameters On dia.DiameterID Equals le.DiameterID
         Join krom In dbiLens.LensKrommings On krom.KrommingID Equals le.KrommingID
         Join sterk In dbiLens.LensSterktes On sterk.SterkteID Equals le.SterkteID _        
Where sterk.sterkte Mod 0.50 = 0 
    Where (le.TypeID = pLensTypeID AndAlso le.GebruiksduurID = pLensPeriodeID _
    AndAlso dia.Diameter = pLensDiaMin _
    AndAlso krom.Kromming = pLensKromMin _
    AndAlso sterk.Sterkte >= pLensSterkteMin AndAlso sterk.Sterkte <= pLensSterkteMax)
                            Select le
```

I've figured out that I Can't do this because i try to proceed the where statement on a query that doesn't yet exists so I should use the Let procedure. But I can't get that one right...
Anybody has an easy example?

thx

Comment: The where right(Cstr....) or where ... Mod... should only work on the join sterk line because  these parameters are in the lenssterktes table

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim halfOrInteger = From n In numbers
                    Where n * 2 Mod 1 = 0
```

or in method-syntax:

```
Dim halfOrInteger = numbers.Where(Function(n) n * 2 Mod 1 = 0)
```

**Edit**: Apparently LINQ-to-SQL cannot translate this to working SQL.

> Arithmetic and comparison operators work as expected in the common
>   language runtime (CLR) except as follows:

- SQL does not support the modulus operator on floating-point numbers.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882653.aspx

I must admit that i've only few experiences with LINQ-to-SQL, but it seems that you cannot use the most useful functions/operator like %/Mod or IndexOfAny. But try following(localizations issues included ;)):

```
Dim halfOrInteger = From n In numbers
                    Let doubleNumString = (n * 2).ToString
                    Let IsDoubleInt = doubleNumString.IndexOf("."c)=-1 _
                              AndAlso doubleNumString.IndexOf(","c)=-1
                    Where IsDoubleInt
                    Select n
```

Comment: thx for the quick respons but both solutions give me the same error " Operand data type float is invalid for modulo operator." And I know that none of the parameters are from type float they are of type double

Comment: The reason seems to be the  first point  here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882653.aspx

Comment: Thx for the help. In this case the solution from andrew morton is more efficiënt. Although Your example gives me more insight in de Let statement. Grtz

Comment: @Bongo: The `let` is similar to a variable in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
Return (From p IN dbi.database
        Join p2 in dbi.database on p2.steID Equals p.SteID
        Where p2.SteID Mod .50 = 0
        Select P).ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you make a list of the values you want to match:

```
Dim requiredSterkte As New List(Of Double)
For i = 2 To 6
    requiredSterkte.Add(i * 0.5)
Next
```

then you can use

```
Where requiredSterkte.Contains(le.Sterkte)
```

Sometimes it isn't worth trying to do everything in one line.